# Can I connect Cloudstack to a Xen Hypervisor with existing vm's?

Tags: xen, cloudstack

I have an existing Xen Hypervisor and I just installed cloudstack on another machine.

In the Cloudstack installation guide it says:

" When you deploy CloudStack, the hypervisor host must not have any VMs already running "

Does this mean I need a new/clean Xen hypervisor installation, or to just turn off any existing VMs in the Xen hypervisor until I get cloudstack to properly connect?

Did some searches but couldn't find an exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should have a clean machine.
Any VMs that existed before you installed Cloudstack will still be there, and may operate properly, but could cause problems with resource allocation. It would be best to export them and then port them back in once Cloudstack is up and running.